# No permissions error on Oculus Quest from ADB on arch linux

Tags: android, linux, debugging, adb, oculusquest

I am currently trying to deploy an apk to my oculus quest over ADB on Arch Linux. After killing/starting the adb server on root and my user, it always prints this:

```
adb devices     
List of devices attached
[device id] no permissions; see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]
```

As far as I'm aware, there should be a prompt on the Oculus Quest that lets me accept USB debugging, but I am not seeing this prompt on either my user or root user, after unplugging and plugging it back in. Developer mode is enabled.

Edit: After doing some investigation it seems as if even after killing the server with `sudo adb kill-server`, the server is automatically restarted under my unprivileged user automatically from some service. I have no idea what is restarting the adb server automatically however.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if the device wasn't getting proper authorization from my user's group because it was not in the android's udev rules. After adding to these rules according to the arch linux wiki and rebooting, I have successfully authenticated.